# How to use toast in react hook?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

**I used a react-toastify and toast.error toast get but toast.success i didn't get**
onClick move one component to other component and i didn't get toast.success
How to get Success toast in moving one component to another component using the hook function??

Comment: can you please add some of your code?

Comment: I've use in signin response and i've used npm i react-toastify   just import and  set toast.error("invalid user name") in rep .catch time and i get notification but success time i didn't get  because signin page to dashboard page move

Comment: It doesn't matter if your page moves. Please add the code you're using or create a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/) for better understanding.